# Home Folder powershell script to exclude disabled users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been working on a powershell script to bulk change the home folder for users in a OU and create a folder for them on the new server. The issue I'm running into though is I need Get-ADUser command to filter out the disabled users in the OU. I found the code I think I need but I'm not sure how to combine it with the OU filter that's already in the script.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TEST,OU=TEST 
Users,DC=TEST,DC=com"
$users | ForEach-Object {
# Assign user's home directory path
$homeDirectory = '\\test.fileserver.com\Users\' + $_.SamAccountName;
Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -HomeDirectory $homeDirectory - 
HomeDrive Q;
# Creates folder
New-Item –path $HomeDirectory -type directory -force
}
```

Thanks

Comment: _I found the code I think I need_ and that would be? Is it perhaps `-Filter 'enabled -eq $false'`

Comment: I believe you are correct I'm just not sure where to put it in the code

Comment: You currently have `-Filter *`... Just replace that

Comment: That worked thanks! I had to change the false to $true for it to only return the enabled users.